# Image on pressing F5/Ctrl+F5

Tags: php, image, caching, image-caching

I'm making a website using PHP. I have an image handler which handles the images and cache them. My problem is when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> many times the images sometimes does not show or not cache. Can anyone help me with that kind of problem or suggest me whats the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

So I am guessing you are pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page. Depending on the browser, <kbd>F5</kbd> refreshes the page and may get new cache content whereas pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> will force a cache refresh.

If you post what browser you are using and possibly a link to the site, we might be able to help more.